# Sts command not found by AWSCLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli, aws-sts

I am trying to get an AWS account ID when i run my shell script by using this line:

```
ACCOUNT_ID=`awscliv2 --region ${S3_REGION} sts get-caller-identity | jq '.Account' | tr -d '"'
```

This is however returning a code 127.

```
awscliv2 - ERROR - Command failed with code 127
```

A lot of the reading i have done is hinting at the command not being in my $PATH. But when i `echo $PATH`, i get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin
```

And `which awscliv2` gives me:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/awscliv2
```

Which shows me that it indeed is in my $PATH. Could someone help me figure out why i am unable to run this command?

Comment: Did you manually rename the command? v2 should install as the command "aws" by default.

Comment: Running `aws --version` will return version information. If you have renamed your command, what happens if you run `awscliv2 --version`?

Comment: Hi @Antoine089 , hope you are well. How have you solved this one? I'm getting the same error